# mysql error after trying put in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert tables from phpmyadmin in SQL, such as:

```sql
INSERT INTO users
(
    steam VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    length INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    unban VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    reason VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    banned SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    leaves SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (steam)
);
```

But I'm getting an error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', length ' at line 3

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that is `CREATE TABLE` syntax, not `INSERT` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Tables need to be exist in db before inserting value in that. so make sure that you are inserting value in that table which have existence in your database.

To create a table you need to fire the below query.

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    steam VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    length INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    unban VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    reason VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    banned SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    leaves SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (steam)
);
```

After creating the table you can directly insert value from you phpmyadmin or you can also do that by executing the below query.

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES
('steam value', 'name of user', '4', 'any unban value', 'any reason value', '0', '0');
```

if you want insert value from you php file than you must need to make a database connection & after that you can use mysql_query() function in insert value in you db

Answer (score 0):

You should create table first:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    steam VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    length INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    unban VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    reason VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    banned SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    leaves SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (steam)
);
```

once it created you can insert:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES
('user steam value', 'user name', 3, 'unban value', 'reason value', 0, 0);
```